# Can I call MVVM cross command method from Ios based on condition?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have below MVVM cross command in my viewmodel. I want to call this based on condition from iOS. Is this possible?

**Command**

```
public IMvxCommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new MvxCommand(async () => await ExecLoginClick()));
    }
}
```

**iOS Binding**

```
var bindings = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
bindings.Bind(username).To(vm => vm.Email);
bindings.Bind(password).To(vm => vm.Password);
bindings.Bind(login_button).To(vm => vm.LoginCommand);
bindings.Bind(forgot_button).To(vm => vm.ForgotCommand);
bindings.Bind(register_button).To(vm => vm.GetSignUpCommand);
//bindings.Bind(btn_facebook).To(vm=>vm.)
bindings.Apply();
```

Comment: Do you want to execute the command manually from your viewcontroller? Or should it only execute, if you click on the button and the condition is true?

Comment: Hi, I want to have some condition in ios like if (condition is true) then call mvvm command otherwise dont call. I am new in MVVMCross so dont know is it possible.. In short i want call command manually from viewcontroller..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CanExecute for this.

```cs
public IMvxCommand LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _loginCommand ?? 
        (_loginCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ExecLoginClick, CanLogin));
    }
}

private bool CanLogin()
{
    if ( /*your condition*/)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private Task ExecLoginClick()
{
    //...
}
```

And in every method, that affects your condition. You have to call

```
LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

The Button is disabled or enabled based on the return value of CanExecute.

If you want to execute your command from your view, you should inherit from the generic `MvxViewController<T>` or `MvxActivity<T>` like.

```cs
public class LoginView : MvxViewController<LoginViewViewModel>
// or
public class LoginView : MvxActivity<LoginViewViewModel>
```

And then you can call

```cs
if(/*condition*/)
{
    ViewModel.LoginCommand.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, can we call by creating the object of viewmodel and call the method from Ios/Android?

Comment: Thanks champ. You saved my day. I have some others questions but i will ask in some other post.